# Как мне убрать type, title и traceId из валидационного ответа (.NET Core web api)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Использую .NET Core 3.1. Простейший проект Web Api. Ничего не кастомизировал. Имею такую модель:

```
public class UpdateProfileRequest
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Такой экшен в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult UpdateProfile(UpdateProfileRequest request)
{
    
    return Ok(new {UserName = "test"});
}
```

Запрашиваю, не передавая при этом поле `Name`. Ожидаемо получаю:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|df89b6cf-4d6da62fe5671a5c."
}
```

Все отлично, но как мне убрать эти "type", "title" и "traceId"? Они мне не нужны. Пошерстил по интернету, не смог найти внятного гайда на этот счет. Мне бы хотелось оставить ответ в таком виде:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ]
  },
  "status": 400,
}
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Эта информация отладочная, а вы запускаете в режиме разработчика. Соберите в release - не будет информации. Да и в режиме разработки можно убрать - закомментируйте строки в Startup.cs `if (env.IsDevelopment()) { app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); }` Но я бы не советовал - отлаживаться-то как будете? Гм, хотя нет, это для exception'ов. Просто соберите в release - должно быть скрыто.

Comment: @AK нет, проблема не ушла. Я сделал dotbet publish -r linux-x64 -o <path here>. Затем запустил проект ./WebApi. Отправляя тот же запрос на тот же эндпоинт я получаю те же лишние для меня поля в ответе.

Comment: Пусть в комментариях хотя бы останется рабочий способ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512802/how-i-can-adjust-which-fields-i-will-have-in-the-response-of-a-model-validation/64517172#64517172